# How to check the given number is digit or not?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, if-statement

How can I check if a number is composed by a single digit?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
n=5
def digit(n):
   for i in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]:
       if ???
           return True
       else:
           return False
```

The output in this case should be `True

`

Comment: what exactly is the issue?

Comment: i  got error in the above code how can i write the code simply

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do

```
def isdigit(n):
    return n in range(10)
```

Comment: Drop the second function. Test 3.5

Comment: @Aryerez you're right, thank you! I was only considering integers

Comment: @Aryerez I thought clarifying it works only with floats was enough, but yes I can remove it of course. But we always make some assumptions on the type of the parameters passed in, don't we?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not saying it's the best way to do it, but it's probably what you meant to do:

```
def digit(n):
    for i in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]:
        if n == i:
            return True
    else:
        return False
digit(5)
```

Output:

```
True
```

Please pay attention that the `else` clause is not part of the `if`, but part of the `for`, which means that it will be executed only if the loop ended without any `return` or `break` during the iterations. You can also not use the `else` at all, and just `return False` after the loop.